# To what extent was nonviolence effective in challenging racism (Civil Rights Movement)?

Tags: civil-rights

I am primarily looking for examples of violent protests in the 1960's which failed. I am hoping to find a protest that was a means of self-defense that resulted in more violence. I am trying to prove that non-violent protests is more effective than violent protests. I have already seen one question that is similar, but I need to find a specific event of self-defense that resulted in more violence instead of challenging racism.

I was trying to find an event that I compare to the Montgomery Bus Boycott to show the effectiveness of Non Violence. Currently I have looked at the Black Panther Party because they advocated for self-defense, but I have yet to find a specific protest/event which self defense was used and resulted in more violence.

Comment: Hi George. Please let us know where you have looked already, and please clarify your question: *I am hoping to compare **this** event* - which event are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was trying to find an event that I compare to the Montgomery Bus Boycott to show the effectiveness of Non Violence. Currently I have looked at the Black Panther Party because they advocated for self-defense, but I have yet to find a specific protest/event which self defense was used and resulted in more violence.

Comment: I all ready checked out the question "Was violent or nonviolent protest more effective in the context of the 1960s Civil Rights Movement?", but I was hoping to find a similar event of self defense that occured around the 1960's so I would be able to make a fair comparison.

Comment: Malcom X might be another place you could look, though I quite frankly know my history well enough to know if he was involved in any specific incident, or merely opposed Martin Luther King Jr.'s nonviolent approach. Still, might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think you should describe why the other topic does not match what you are looking for in the post.

Comment: @George Welcome to the site - just a heads up - discussion in comments is an anti-pattern.  The original poster should edit the question to address the issues raised in comments.  (and then flag the comment as "no longer needed")

Answer (score 3):

I see two potential approaches you could take.

The closest thing to a single event that comes to mind is [the apparent assassination of Fred Hampton](https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-black-panthers-raid-fred-hampton-50-years-20191203-kbzgztrvtfh7tp7x4ggtvhncpm-story.html). Regardless of who fired the first shot, you could easily argue that this was effective repression that weakened the movement. You could also argue that it occurred because of the Black Panther Party's posture on self-defense (although some might say it had more to do with other aspects of their agenda.)

The other approach might be to look at what lead the civil rights movement toward nonviolence in the first place. [Here](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1080/713687897) is an article which "explores how blacks in the rural South tried to defend themselves before civil rights" and then how that changed over time. You could say that current of self-defense actually persisted well in to the 1960s in in the form of [The Deacons for Defense and Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deacons_for_Defense_and_Justice). Looking at it this way, it might actually go against your thesis, suggesting that nonviolence and self-defense actually went hand-in-hand.